# How do I install Apache Portable Runtime?

Tags: linux, svn, installation

My Apache is installed by `yum install apache`

And now I'm trying to install subversion server from source following instructions [here](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/subversion.html).

But when I try to configure,get an error:

```
[root@vps303 subversion-1.6.9]# ./configure
configure: Configuring Subversion 1.6.9
configure: creating config.nice
checking for gcc... gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
...
checking for APR... no
configure: WARNING: APR not found
The Apache Portable Runtime (APR) library cannot be found.
Please install APR on this system and supply the appropriate
--with-apr option to 'configure'

or

get it with SVN and put it in a subdirectory of this source:

   svn co \
    http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/branches/1.2.x \
    apr

Run that right here in the top level of the Subversion tree.
Afterwards, run apr/buildconf in that subdirectory and
then run configure again here.

Whichever of the above you do, you probably need to do
something similar for apr-util, either providing both
--with-apr and --with-apr-util to 'configure', or
getting both from SVN with:

   svn co \
    http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr-util/branches/1.2.x \
    apr-util

configure: error: no suitable apr found
```

How do I get around this problem?

BTW,will both client and server software be installed by compiling from source?

Answer (score 1):

`svnserve` is included in the `subversion` package already, which can also be installed via `yum`.